# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: python, database, oracle, oracle11g, pycharm

Following line of code shows

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE address(addressid int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT=1,addressline varchar(10),city varchar(10),zip int,state varchar(10)) ''')
```

Before adding the constraints the code was running without an error but now it shows the error.

Answer (score 1):

It's the order of the options, first specify the column, then the constraint.

In Oracle 12, use:

```
CREATE TABLE address(addressid INT GENERATED AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  addressline VARCHAR(10), city VARCHAR(10), zip int, state varchar(10));
```

In Oracle 11 and earlier, there is no easy replacement for `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you'll have to use a sequence and a trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE address(addressid INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  addressline VARCHAR(10), city VARCHAR(10), zip int, state varchar(10));

CREATE SEQUENCE addressid_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER addressid_tbi BEFORE INSERT ON address FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN :new.addressid := addressid_seq.nextval; END;
```

Comment: Another hint: use VARCHAR2 instead of INT for the zip code, you'll avoid problems with leading zeros like Boston, MA 02101.

Comment: Thanks, i made the changes but error still persists, cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE address(addressid int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,addressline varchar(10),city varchar(10),zip int,state varchar(10)) ''')
error shows - cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-02000: missing ( keyword

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? Please edit your post and add a tag, f.i. oracle11g or oracle12c, as the answer depends on it.

Comment: I'm using oracle11g

Comment: Ah, I see. That's the problem then, there is neither `AUTO_INCREMENT` nor `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` in Oracle 11g. I edited the answer accordingly.